# Print in getter of a property not working?

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators

I am new to python, currently trying to learn properties.

```
class Car(object):
    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self._speed = speed
        print("set speed to {}".format(self.speed))


    def get_speed(self):
        return self._speed
        print("the speed is {}".format(self.speed))


    speed = property(fget = get_speed, fset=set_speed)

car1 = Car()
car1.speed = 170
x = car1.speed
```

The output I get is `set speed to 170`

That is all well and fine, and there is no surprise here since `car1.speed` was called. However, why was there never a `"The speed is 170"` printline?
`car1.speed` was called in the same manner? Is there something I have not understood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used a `return` statement *before* the `print()` call. The function execution *ends* at that point, the `print()` is never reached:

```
def get_speed(self):
    # return ends a function
    return self._speed
    # anything beyond this point is ignored
    print("the speed is {}".format(self.speed))
```

Put the `print()` call *before* the return statement:

```
def get_speed(self):
    print("the speed is {}".format(self._speed))
    return self._speed
```

I corrected the `print()` function to show `self._speed` (*with* an underscore in the attribute name), otherwise you'd get into an infinite recursion (since `self.speed` would trigger the property again getter). You probably want to do the same in the `set_speed()` function, as that'll trigger the `get_speed()` getter too and you'll see `the speed is <newspeed>` printed before `set speed to <newspeed>` is printed each time you change the speed:

```
class Car(object):
    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self._speed = speed
        print("set speed to {}".format(speed))

    def get_speed(self):
        print("the speed is {}".format(self._speed))
        return self._speed

    speed = property(fget = get_speed, fset=set_speed)
```

Next, you can use the `property` object as a *decorator*; the resulting `property` instance has a `setter()` method that can then be re-used to decorate the setter too:

```
class Car(object):
    @property
    def speed(self):
        print("the speed is {}".format(self._speed))
        return self._speed

    @speed.setter
    def speed(self, speed):
        self._speed = speed
        print("set speed to {}".format(speed))
```

See [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) as to how that works.

Comment: Wow, what a blunder. Thank you.